# Webpack resolve svg

Tags: javascript, css, svg, webpack

Installed in node:

```
npm install svg-url-loader --save
```

I have added to the webpack.config.js:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
        {test: /\.svg/, loader: 'svg-url-loader'},
    ]
}
```

To the Page.jsx:

```
require("svg-url!C:/../WebApp/main_page_assets/02_general_alerts_icons.svg");
require("C:/../WebApp/css/dashboard/dashboard.css");
```

And in my css:

```
.test {
    background: url('../../main_page_assets/02_general_alerts_icons.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

And I receive:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!../css/dashboard/dashboard.css
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'svg-url-loader' in C:\..\W
bApp\css\dashboard
 @ ./~/css-loader!../css/dashboard/dashboard.css 6:74-135
```

What can be the reason? Paths issues? i have been playing with the paths back and forth and cant make it work

Comment: Fixed, the assets(css,svgs) needs to be in the src folder

Comment: Yes. And FWIW, I don't think you need to require in the SVG to Page.jsx if you're only using it in the CSS file. You would only need to require it in directly if you are using it in an image tag or inline style within Page.jsx.

Comment: You should answer and accept your own answer to your question for posterity's sake and to complete the life-cycle of your question.

Comment: @gfullam you are right about requiring for the svg, and yea I will answer and accept in a bit